# Date criteria not working with mongodb using spring data

Tags: mongodb, date, spring-data-mongodb

I am query mongodb using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb
1. How to fetch data from mongo for a specific date; eq does not work
2. how to fetch data for a date range; I am able to get data using gte and lte. But if gte and lte date is same then does not return any record.

```
 Query query = new Query();
 Criteria criteria = Criteria.where(field1).is("Value1");
 criteria.and(dateField).gte("2019-04-04").lte("2019-04-04"); 
 query.addCriteria(criteria);
 return mongoTemplate.find(query, MyClass.class);
```

This does not return any record even though "dateField: 2019-04-04T10:02:58.957+00:00" exist in database

Can you please provide some example code.
Thanks

Comment: You need a valid date format to compare in DB, ex in js: new Date("2019-04-04")

Comment: Can you please post some sample data?

Comment: sample code and data is there in the question.  {_id:1, dateField
:
2019-04-05T10:02:58.957+00:00}